# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0 when syncing project

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

I'm trying to use Google Play Services on my Android app to get the device's last known location, but when I try to add the gradle dependency:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'`

I get the following error:

`A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/9.6.0/play-services-9.6.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/9.6.0/play-services-9.6.0.jar
         file:/home/user/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/9.6.0/play-services-9.6.0.pom
         file:/home/user/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/9.6.0/play-services-9.6.0.jar
         file:/home/user/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/9.6.0/play-services-9.6.0.pom
         file:/home/user/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/9.6.0/play-services-9.6.0.jar`

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's my build.gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "app"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 24
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }


        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
        compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        compile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-mockito-release-full', version: '1.6.4'
        compile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your gradle file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your SDK's `Android Support Repository` and `Google Play services` first. See if it syncs after.

Comment: How can I do this from command line? (I'm using ubuntu 16.04 just in case)

Comment: I get a link to Install Repository when I try building with Intellij, but the link does nothing.

Comment: Go to your android sdk dir -> tools and run the script named `android`. Then scroll down and update the aforementioned two packages.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have fixed the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening due to google play services SDK not being installed in your android studio package. Follow the Android Developers guide on how to set up google play services in your application. There is a link in it to facilitate on how to set up SDK before you add the dependencies in your package.
[Google Developers Guide : Google Play services setup](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup/)

Answer (score 0):

In your project level build.gradle file, under buildscript > dependencies,
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'